# Android display only mp3 with ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, mp3

I'm trying to display just MP3 files with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Music File"), FIND_MUSIC);
```

But it ends up listing *.3gp files as well.  How can I limit to just *.mp3 files only?

I've tried setType("mp3") but then the intent isn't able to find any app that loads the file.

Answer (score 9):

The correct MIME type you need to pass to setType to show only mp3 files is "audio/mpeg3". Also "audio/x-mpeg3" should work. Check this out for a full list of MIME types: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full

Answer (score 5):

"audio/mpeg3" did not work for me.
I logged the mime type of mp3,

```
mimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3");
        Log.e("mime:", mimeType);
```

It was **"audio/mpeg"**